# Joomla 1.5 Iframes

Tags: html, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a joomla 1.5 installation and for some reason when ever i put in an iframe into the site joomla strips it out.

I copy and past this code into the code editor and chose save and it will remove it. How do i make it stop this?

```
<iframe src ="client_login.html" width="100%" height="300px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when trying to embed Google map widgets into articles.  The solution that I found was to do the following:

1. In Article Preferences
   (Content->Article
   Manager->Parameters), under
   "Filtering Options", *de*select
   the group associated with your user
   account -- this will disable the
   server-side sanitization
2. On your
       user account page (Site->User
       Manager->*your name*), under
       "Parameters" set "User Editor" to
       "No Editor" -- this will prevent the
       WYSIWYG editor from stripping out
       the IFRAME tag

Now obviously this solution has one glaring problem: **you're not going to want to do this for groups the general public will fall into**.  In my case, it was just for "Super Administrator" so I considered it an acceptable risk.

You can easily toggle the user editor on and off, so if you only have to add such content sparingly it shouldn't be too terribly annoying.  The other advantage here is that this is a stock Joomla! 1.5 solution so future upgrades shouldn't break this workaround, and it doesn't require an extension which may impact performance.

Comment: On step one how exactly do i deselect my group? It just has a static text box of all the groups and then two text boxes under it to add even more items to filter.

I guess i could do whitelist but i dont want to add everysingle html tag.

Comment: A static text box?  My installation of 1.5 has a listbox labeled "Filter Groups"...you should just simply be able to Control-click the appropriate group to deselect it (assuming there are others selected at the time).  By default, all groups should be selected (and thus highlighted in the listbox).

Answer (score 1):

After trying Whitelist in Article manager, and use iframe plugins and not working, `sourcerer` plugin did it. Use the `[[ ]]` to replace `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried plugins before to do this but none of them seemed to work either. I found a REALLY simple plugin thats works perfect.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-&-design/popups-&-iframes/4144/details

To add an iframe with it all you do is  {iframe}url{/iframe} you can set width and height and everything.